# Fix the execution error in the decision tree in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, decision-tree, sklearn-pandas

I want to implement the decision tree in my database but I got the following error. Can anyone guide me?

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, df, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

decisionTree1 = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="entropy", max_depth=5, min_samples_split=5)

decisionTree1.fit(X_train,y_train)
predicted_y_train = decisionTree1.predict(X_train)
predicted_y_test = decisionTree1.predict(X_test)
```

**Error**

```
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'normal'
```

**DataSet**
[image]

Comment: Can we have a sample of your csvfile ?

Comment: @Wind56 Of course, but how do I upload the file here?

Comment: @Wind56 I added a photo of it

Comment: I think you probably should have only float in your dataframe. You can select the fields you want with the following df[["age", "bp"]] if you just want age and bp. If you need the data as string, consider transforming them into numbers (normal = 0, abnormal = 1 for instance)

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: as I know most models work only on numbers. You have to convert strings to numbers - ie. `LabelEncoding()`,